# Select columns that are not null in any record

Tags: mysql, sql, select, dynamic-columns

I need to analyze a MySQL table and want to determine all *columns* that never contain `NULL`, 0 or an empty string in any record in that table.
I do not have a clue how to do that, since MySQL expects me to select the columns at the beginning of the statement. I thought I could maybe rotate the table by 90° and then do something like

`SELECT column_header FROM rotated_table WHERE record_1 <> NULL AND record_2 <> NULL AND [...]`

But this seems to be a lot of work.
Is there an easier way to get the information i require?

**Update example**:

Table1:

```
name        street      zip
MyName      1st Ave.    1000
OtherName   2nd Street  NULL
```

My statement now should show something like:

```
name        street
MyName      1st Ave.
OtherName   2nd Street
```

Because the column *zip* contains a `NULL` value.
If there was an additional row like

```
name        street      zip
MyName      1st Ave.    1000
OtherName   2nd Street  NULL
NULL        Foo blvd.   3453
```

It should return

```
street
1st Ave.
2nd Street
Foo blvd.
```

Because *name* and *zip* contain at least one `NULL` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the behavior of `COUNT` ignoring `NULL` values to your advantage.

Subtract the count of the column you're examining from the count of the number of rows.  Any column that returns a value of `0` does not contain a `NULL` value.  You'll need to use a `CASE` statement to convert any values you consider to be "empty" into `NULL`.

This approach also eliminates the need copying the entire table in order to "rotate" it.

I whipped up an example [here in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e858f4/15) which should work for you.

Here's the content of [my SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e858f4/15) in case the link becomes unusable:

```
CREATE TABLE address
(
    address int auto_increment primary key, 
    street1 varchar(20),
    street2 varchar(20),
    city varchar(20),
    state varchar(20),
    zip int,
    comment varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO address
(street1, street2, city, state, zip, comment)
VALUES
('123 Main St.', null, 'Cleveland', 'OH', 44123, ''),
('1313 Mockingbird Ln.', null, 'Cleveland', 'OH', 0, 'Unknown zip'),
('321 Main St.', 'Apt #1', 'Cleveland', 'OH', 44123, ''),
('321 Main St.', 'Apt #2', 'Cleveland', 'OH', 44123, '');

SELECT
COUNT(*) rows, -- not really needed, you can remove this
COUNT(*) - COUNT(CASE ad.street1 WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE ad.street1 END) empty_street1,
COUNT(*) - COUNT(CASE ad.street2 WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE ad.street2 END) empty_street2,
COUNT(*) - COUNT(CASE ad.city WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE ad.city END) empty_city,
COUNT(*) - COUNT(CASE ad.state WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE ad.state END) empty_state,
-- Change the value being compared based on the column type.  Strings '', numbers 0, etc.
COUNT(*) - COUNT(CASE ad.zip WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE ad.zip END) empty_zip,
COUNT(*) - COUNT(CASE ad.comment WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE ad.comment END) empty_comment
FROM address ad;
```

Which results in:

```
ROWS    EMPTY_STREET1   EMPTY_STREET2   EMPTY_CITY  EMPTY_STATE     EMPTY_ZIP   EMPTY_COMMENT
4       0               2               0           0               1           3
```

Comment: Bah - I somehow missed the `0` and empty string requirement.  I'll revise soon.

Comment: Here you go - I believe this should do what you asked.

Comment: Using [count(*)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) now because it always counts all records.

Comment: Thanks. This is nearly what I want:
Is there now additionally a possibility to exclude columns from being displayed, iff they return `0`?
This is actually my key aspect.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, then for my example above you would only want `EMPTY_STREET2`, `EMPTY_ZIP`, and `EMPTY_COMMENT` to be displayed?

Comment: Take a look at this modified version of my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e858f4/45).  If that fits the bill I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @RichardNeumann, I assume the SQLFiddle in my previous comment was correct.  Let me know so I can update the answer here if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The correct comparison to `NULL` is `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.  So:

```
SELECT column_header
FROM rotated_table
WHERE record_1 IS NOT NULL AND record_2 IS NOT NULL AND [...];
```

However "record" is an odd name for columns.  You want to be sure the column names are in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Sorry, I totally mixed up columns and rows in the question.
It really is about selecting only _columns_ that are never null in any row.

Comment: @RichardNeumann . . . I would suggest that you delete this question and ask another question.  Include sample data and your desired results.